# Como crear una una condicion if cuando esta en reponsive desing

Tags: javascript, html, funciones, condiciones

tengo una duda es que necesito, que una funcion solo se ejecute cuando esta en reponsive o la opcion de celular algo asi

```
function a() {
if(condicion para que solo se ejecute en reponsive){
}
else
{
(aqui que no haga nada)
}
```

Y no me refiero al css, es que en mi pagina que estoy haciendo hay unos botones, en el cual son diferentes al de pc y el reponsive, y esa funcion quiero que solo funcione en reponsive y no en el de pc

Seria de mucha ayuda, Gracias

Comment: podes usar el objeto [Window Screen](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp) para detectar el tamaño de la pantalla

Comment: De igual forma, puedes borrar el else, no lo necesitas para nada. A todo esto, para la próxima, intenta explicar en qué lenguaje estás trabajando y expresar qué has intentado hasta el momento. Esto ayudará a tener más buenas respuestas. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Creo que estas un poco confundido en cuanto eso... dejame explicarte, cuando se trata de responsive design lo ideal es que esto lo maneje `CSS` y no `Javascript` pues se supone que `CSS` esta hecho para esto.

Ahora bien te preguntaras... y entonces como hago que cambien ciertos elementos dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla con `css`?, muy sencillo para eso existen los `media querys` en `CSS`, lo primero que debes hacer es agregar la meta etiqueta viewport en el `HTML` para que la pagina reconozca esto:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.redDiv{
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .redDiv{
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class = "redDiv"></div>
</body>
```

En el ejemplo superior definimos unos cuantos estilos basicos de `css`, y podemos observar que nuestro elemento `HTML` tiene una clase definida llamada `redDiv` la cual en uno de sus estilos definimos que tenga fondo de color rojo:

```
.redDiv{
    ...
    background: red;
    ...
}
```

sin embargo en el ejemplo vemos que esta de color **azul**, porque pasa esto?

Pues porque en nuestro media query definimos anteriormente que para un ancho de pantalla de `900px` o superior las reglas aplicadas a la clase `redDiv` cambiaran:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .redDiv{
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

De esta manera no solo hacemos que `css` se encargue de manera automatica de realizar estos cambios de estado, si no que ademas resulta muchisimo mas eficiente que usar `javascript` para lo mismo.

De hecho si quieres ver magia deberias intentar darle en el snippet al boton de ampliar para poder ver asi una diferencia que hay y lo que ocurre al cambiar de cierto ancho de pantalla.

Comment: Por cierto, se que eres nuevo usuario, asi que te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, en caso de que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda o haya solucionado tu problema recuerda que puedes darle al boton que parece un chulo para poder asi ambos obtener puntos de reputacion en el sitio, espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado.

Comment: PD: las medidas oficiales en el que se reconoce la pagina como si fuera usada en un dispositivo movil no estan estaticamente definidas en CSS ni en los media querys, es enrealidad el usuario el que opta por poner un ancho u alto en el que la pagina se vuelve responsive, sin embargo en internet hay estandares de medidas responsive por si quieres seguir algun estandar al momento de cambiar a responsive.

Comment: puedes ver otra vez la pregunta

Comment: Hola @Gaudencio, puedes revisar otra vez la respuesta de Riven? Eso soluciona/responde a tu pregunta.